# Why isn't the return as expected?

Tags: scala

Could you please run println(func("ctnkh"))? I got 4, but isn't it supposed to be 5?

```
def func(s: String): Int = {
  if(s == "")
    return 0
  val len = s.length
  var max = Int.MinValue
  for(i <- 0 until len)
    for(j <- i+1 to len) {
      val ss = s.substring(i, j)
      if(ss.mkString == ss.toSet.mkString) {
        if(ss.length > max)
          max = ss.length
      }
    }

  max
}
```

I'll appreciate any of your hints

Comment: Also, in such cases, you can use the debugger to know why the result is not as you expect

Comment: you can not rely on the order of the characters in Set

Answer (score 2):

because `ss.toSet.mkString` will be in a different order than `ss.mkString`
for ex. try the following:

```
  val str = "ctnkh"
  println(str.mkString)
  println(str.toSet.mkString)
```

output is:

> ctnkh
>
> ntchk

so the result will never be 5

**edit:** as mentioned in the comments you can't rely on the order of the characters in the `Set` as this order is not predictable.

Comment: Worth noting that order is stable for the small specialized set implementations, so it might work up to size 4 but then fail at 5.

Answer (score 1):

You probably meant: `ss.distinct`. It drops all duplicate characters from the string, and preserves the order of the remaining characters.

```
def func(s: String): Int = {
  val len = s.length
  var max = 0
  for(i <- 0 until len) {
    for(j <- i+1 to len) {
      val ss = s.substring(i, j)
      if(ss == ss.distinct) {
        max = max.max(ss.length)
      }
    }
  }
  max
}

println(func("ctnkh"))
```

gives `5`, as you expected.

Comment: method distinct in class StringOps is deprecated (since 2.13.0): Use `s.toSeq.distinct.unwrap` instead of `s.distinct`

Comment: @som-snytt Thanks! I tested it only on 2.12.x, so I didn't get any deprecation warnings. I'd like to point out that my proposal is merely a random guess - if one wanted to write code "more or less equivalent" to what OP wrote, then one would have to check whether all characters in the substring are distinct *and* whether a random permutation of the characters is the same as the original. The original code simply doesn't make much sense, so I didn't attempt to "optimize" it in any way.

Comment: Also thanks for reminding me they gave us distinct, for a while.

Answer (score 0):

For your test, it's sufficient to check size:

```
if (ss.length == ss.toSet.size) max = max.max(ss.length)
```

since iteration order is extraneous.